# PowerBI: Conditional Column - Check if the same item was there in the previous month

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In PowerBI I have a dataset comprised of customer numbers (C1, C2, C3, ...) and dates when they placed their orders.

In the query I now want to add a custom column that gives me a 1 if the customer number appeared at least once in the previous month and a 0 if it didn't.

| Customer_Number | Date | In_prev_month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 01.01.2022 | 0 |
| C2 | 01.01.2022 | 0 |
| C3 | 01.01.2022 | 0 |
| C2 | 01.02.2022 | 1 |
| C3 | 01.02.2022 | 1 |
| C4 | 01.02.2022 | 0 |

Comment: Where is your sample data and expected output?

Comment: I edited it (unfortunately the layout is not particularly nice). The Column "In_prev_month" is what I am looking for.

Comment: I would try the accepted answer with more test data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this as a calculated column (be aware that it is checking the previous date only not the month but it seems your database structure fits in)

```
In_prev_month 2 =
VAR _customer = 'Table'[Customer_Number ]
VAR _date = 'Table'[Date ]
RETURN
    IF (
        CALCULATE (
            COUNT ( 'Table'[Customer_Number ] ),
            FILTER (
                ALL ( 'Table' ),
                _date > ( 'Table'[Date ] )
                    && _customer = ( 'Table'[Customer_Number ] )
            )
        ) > 0,
        1,
        0
    )
```

Comment: Yeap, Bingo! Tried and Tested. Congrats, @UmutK . Upvoted it.

Comment: @OzanSen Merci 

Comment: Does this limit to only previous month? i.e. will this not show 1 when there is a value 2 or 3 months ago?

Comment: @David it checks only the previous date actually, not the month. So, yes, it will show...

Comment: OP should be aware of this as their question asked for previous month only.